# C#, how to avoid recursion elegantly?

Tags: c#

I've got an event-function, where the code inside the function may trigger calling the same function again (because a message loop is used). How can I avoid this or better "detect" this most elegantly? When it comes to multiple thread synchronization one could write:

```
public void Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(m_Object)
    {

        <Code, which can trigger Closing again>

    }
}
```

But in my case it is the same thread that may call the same function and thus lock fails to work.

Comment: I don't really understand the question - if you don't want it to run, don't call it?

Comment: <Code, which can trigger Closing again> has to be called once. But this can call Closing again and then <Code, which can trigger Closing again> should not be called again.

Comment: Can't you avoid the <Code, which can trigger Closing again> by taking a bool variable?

Answer (score 4):

Introduce a `private bool m_IsClosing` variable that indicates whether closing is already in progress.

```
public void Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (m_Object)
    {
        if (m_IsClosing)
            return;

        m_IsClosing = true;

        try
        {    
            // Code, which can trigger Closing again
        }
        finally
        {        
            m_IsClosing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it's particularly elegant, but without knowing more about what you're doing, I can't any better solution.

**Edit:** adapted example for possible exceptions while closing.

Comment: That does work, but what if <Code which can trigger Closing again> raises an exception? Not smart enough!

Comment: Then wrap it in a try..catch?

Comment: catch the exception and set m_IsClosing back to false.

Answer (score 2):

Add a member of your class `closingInProgress` initialized to false.  Then:

```
public void Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (closingInProgress)
    {
        return;
    }

    try 
    {
         closingInProgress = true;
         <Code, which can trigger Closing again>
    } 
    finally 
    {
         closingInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely ok. But not very elegant, I'm afraid.

Comment: The only reason you could use `lock` in your original example is because there is special syntax built-in to C# for multithread synchronization.  There is no language support in C# for this type of lock, but it only takes a few lines of code.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure if I missed something, something easy like "lock" or so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a private field to remember whether Closing has already been called.  If it has, then abort from the procedure:

```
private bool ClosingDone;
public void Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ClosingDone)
    {
        ClosingDone = true;
        // Code, which can trigger Closing again
    }
}
```

Comment: Should work in single threaded situations, but this would also prevent consecutive `Closing` calls, not just recursive. This might or might not be intended.

Comment: That is okay. But only if Closing() is supposed to be called really only once. What if it should be possible to call is several times successively?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have a flag available in your class which indicates the event is being handled. Using this flag, you can determine whether to run the method again when called recursively.

```
private bool m_IsClosing;

public void Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(m_Object)
    {
        // Check for state.
        if(m_IsClosing)
            return;

        m_IsClosing = true;

        try
        {
            // The rest of your code.
        }
        finally
        {
            m_IsClosing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The only difficulty will be ensuring you don't read or modify this value elsewhere without entering a critical section locked on `m_Object`. Otherwise, it should prevent the event handler doing any work recursively.

Comment: Absolutely ok. But not very elegant, I'm afraid.

Comment: It isn't pretty, but it is simple. I likes me some simple. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old, but how about that:

```
    public class Locker : IDisposable
{
    bool _isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
    }

    private Locker()
    {
        _isActive = false;
    }

    public static Locker Create()
    {
        return new Locker();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _isActive = false;
    }


    public Locker Activate()
    {
        _isActive = true;
        return this;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    Locker lo = Locker.Create();

    private void Foo()
    {
        if (lo.IsActive) return;
        using(lo.Activate())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
            Bar();
        }
    }

    private void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        Foo();
    }
```

Method Foo() is only called once. *using* makes sure, that lo is deactivated, even if an error occures.